# Ruby replace html entity with hexadecimal equivalent

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there a way to use gsub (or something else) in Ruby to replace a string with its hexadecimal equivalent? In Mysql you'd do something like this:

```
    self.connection.execute("UPDATE `dvd_actor` SET actor = replace(actor, '&pound,', CHAR(163));")
```

I'm rewriting this in Rails and using gsub, something like this:

```
self.actor = actor.gsub(/&pound;/, "£").strip if actor =~ /&pound;/
```

But I already have all the lines written with the hexadecimal character and I'm trying to avoid finding out which character is which (some of them require copy/pasting because I don't have them in the english keyboard).

I tried this (which I saw in a post here):

```
actor.gsub(/&quot;/) { "0x134".hex  } if actor =~ /&quot;/
```

But that doesn't do the trick, it produces a number.

Or better yet, maybe there's a gem that already does that? Basically take the HTML values and fix them? Oh, that would be nice.

Comment: Does `"0x134".hex.to_s(16)` make it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try `"0x134".hex.to_s(16)`. It converts "0x134" into "134".

Comment: That's just it, the result has to be a string, not a number. It's the value of that character in hex. Each letter of the alphabet has a hex value, I need to convert the value to a string. A lowercase 'a' is hex 62 for example: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found it: a gem called htmlentities is supposed to do just what I want. So I have this:

```
ampersands = where("actor LIKE ?", "%&%;%")
ampersands.each do |actor|
  fixed_actor = fixer.decode(actor.actor) 
  self.update(actor.id, :actor => fixed_actor)
```